# How to make a 3x3 matrix with arbitrary numbers in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, rstudio

Im not aware of any direct commands to do this in R. Any inputs?

Comment: Do you mean an array? `array(data = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[4:6], LETTERS[7:9]))`

Comment: no. i actually need a matrix

Comment: `matrix(data = 1:9, nrow = 3)`

Comment: thank you! but I have a question, don't arbitrary mean any number which means that the number in the matrix could be anything? like it could be from 10:18?

Comment: `matrix(sample(1:100, 9, replace = TRUE), nrow = 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a 3x3 matrix, do this:

```
matrix(something, nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

But you need to replace `something` with however you want to make "arbitrary" numbers.  Use `runif(9)` for a random (uniformly distributed) real number between 0 and 1.  Use `sample(1:100, 9, T)` to draw 9 numbers from the integers 1 through 100 with replacement.  Use `rnorm(9)` to draw 9 numbers from a standard normal distribution.  Etc.

Comment: apparently the problem did not specify anything with regards to the distribution of the numbers. what is the norm in dealing with these types of situations?

Comment: What is "the problem"?  Is this a homework assignment?  A request from a client or boss?  That is something that needs to be clarified with whomever is assigning the problem.  If this is a homework assignment, my guess is that it doesn't matter, and that the point is just to make a matrix (literally, any matrix).

Comment: This is a homework assignment that says "make a 3x3 matrix with arbitrary numbers". I'm concerned if I'm having the right matrix or not since the next two questions require extracting the third column and then the first row of the matrix.

Comment: Sounds to me like the assignment is focused on the procedure and not the result, and so it doesn't matter what you put in your matrix.